# Rolling a die twice in either order with not mutual exclusive events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading the following problem:

> If a single die is rolled twice, find the probability of rolling an
> odd number and a number greater than $4$ in any either order

My solution:
Probability of rolling an odd number = $$\frac{3}{6}$$
Probability of rolling a number greater than $4$ = $$\frac{2}{6}$$
Since the events are not mutually exclusive ($5$ is counted twice) the probabilty of throwing an odd number followed by a number greater than $4$:
$$\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{6} - \frac{1}{36} = \frac{5}{36}$$

The probablity of throwing a number greater than $4$ followed by an odd number is: $$\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{6} - \frac{1}{36} = \frac{5}{36}$$

Therefore the my final solution is $$\frac{5}{36} + \frac{5}{36} = \frac{10}{36}$$

But it is wrong, as the solution states that it should be $$\frac{11}{36}$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is 1/36, and why do you think it corrects for double counting?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins: The $5$ is odd and greater than $4$ so to avoid counting that twice I subtract this

Comment: As stated by @Karl below, the mistake seems to be in subtracting it from both orders

Comment: @AleksejsFomins: I thought that if events are not mutually independent we subtract the common event occurence. E.g. if the question was about the probability of odd followed by number greater than $4$, should I subtract the $1$ occurence of $5$? I apply this logic for the reverse order too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome potentially counted twice is $(5,5)$, not $5$.

The number of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is odd and $b>4$ is $3\times2=6$. This includes $(5,5)$.

The number of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a>4$ and $b$ is odd is $2\times3=6$. This includes $(5,5)$.

The sum of these is $6+6=12$, but $(5,5)$ was counted twice; there are actually only $11$ pairs in the union of these two sets.

Comment: I thought that when having events that are not mutually exclusive we always subtract the $\bigcap$. So for `the number of pairs (,) where  is odd and >4 is 3×2=6.` I should not include (5,5)

Comment: I'd suggest just trying to think clearly about the outcomes you want to count instead of focusing on formulaic rules. If we wanted the probability of getting odd or $>4$ in *one* roll of the die, your approach would be applicable: $$|\{odd\}\cup\{>4\}|=|\{odd\}|+|\{>4\}|-|\{odd\}\cap\{>4\}|=|\{1,3,5\}|+|\{5,6\}|-|\{5\}|=3+2-1=4.$$ But for the given problem we instead have $$|\{(odd,>4)\}\cup\{(>4,odd)\}|=|\{(odd,>4)\}|+|\{(>4,odd)\}|-|\{(odd,>4)\}\cap\{(>4,odd)\}|=6+6-1=11.$$

Answer (score 2):

In saying that "5 is counted twice", meaning (presumably) you're removing the duplicate event $(5, 5)$, what you should be doing is saying "The event $(5, 5)$ is part of both of the cases I've considered, so I need to only count it once, so I will remove it once from my calculation."

Instead, what it looks like you've done is removed it from *both* of your cases, each of which assumes the other case has already counted it.

Comment: Since an odd number and a number greater than $4$ are not mutually exclusive, my understanding is that since $5$ appears in both events it should be counted once. Hence if we focus on odd followed by a number greater than $4$ we should subtract $1$ case. Similar logic for the reverse order.

Comment: In rolling an odd number followed by a number greater than 4, rolling the 5 first isn't the same as rolling the 5 second so you don't remove it.

Comment: There are only 36 possibilities anyway, so try writing them out explicitly and counting them all? That might help you see what you missed.